# What is this Growth On an Eastern Spruce tree

Tags: identification, growth

Do you know what this odd looking growth is?
[image: Strange growth on Spruce Tree needing ID]

Comment: Cones? Cones could take several years to grown. The smaller (out of focus): flowers, which will growth up in different stages.